# Question about speed of matrix calculation MATLAB VS. C++

Tags: c++, matlab

I am using Armadillo library to do matrix calculations in C++.

As far as I know, C++ should be faster than Matlab.

To compare the speed of calculation, I made the simplest code.

But when I run the same code as below. It seems like Matlab is faster than C++.

So both of the codes get the maximum value of a given cube and the time was measured based on how much did it take to find the maximum value(except for data allocation).

1.Code for Matlab

```
clear all;

v = rand(1000,1000,100);
tic
[m,i]= max(v);
toc
```

2.Code for C++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>
#include <armadillo>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>

#define ARMA_NO_DEBUG

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main()
{   
    double max_val;
    double duration;
    Cube<double> Val(1000, 1000, 100, fill::randn);
    clock_t start;
    start = clock();
    max_val = Val.max();
    duration = (clock() - start) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    cout << "printf: " << duration << '\n';
}
```

While Matlab takes about 0.04 seconds, C++ takes about 0.15 seconds.

I think at least for this code, there should be no issue of making the C++ code more efficient because this is already too simple.

So I was wondering C++ is slower than Matlab in terms of matrix calculation.

Or maybe, C++ is slower in the simple model but becomes faster in the complex model which contains some loop??

Or should I choose a different library other than Armadillo to speed up?

Comment: What compiler and compiler flags are you using?

Comment: I am using Visual studio.

Comment: Are you building a release or debug build?

Comment: Note that the math functions of matlab are not written in matlab, but generally in fortran or C or maybe C++.

Comment: I am building a release

Comment: are you creating a matrix of double in Matlab as well?

Comment: If I do this 'v = rand(1000,1000,100);' Doesn't it automatically create a cube of double?

Comment: I would not calling finding the maximum a matrix operation only because you use it on a matrix. The shape of the data doesn't matter at all for this operation. Is either Matlab or Armadillo parallelizing this? For actual matrix operations to be fast in C++ I would recommend the "Blaze" library, but I don't even know if calculating the maximum is part of it.

Comment: @ChangseokMa the question is if Matlab uses doubles or floats per default.

Comment: @PaulG. Matlab uses doubles by default

Comment: "Is either Matlab or Armadillo parallelizing this?" Matlab is parallelizing this. See https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95958-which-matlab-functions-benefit-from-multithreaded-computation.

Comment: You are comparing apples to oranges. You need to know how the max function in MATLAB  and your C++ library are implemented. You will find that the max function in MATLAB is highly optimized, hence the much faster speed. A more useful comparison is the speed of the same implementation of max or another function in the two languages. Even then, you need to run it multiple times to average out the speed.

Comment: Also, you need to change your line for max in MATLAB to "val= max(v(:));" otherwise MATLAB  finds the maximum along the first dimension.